# VB.Net - Shadows do not hide the original property

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I created a specific user control with two ComboBox, inherets from UserControl

```
Public Class CodLibCombo : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

Then I needed a specific "Enabled" Property, that can Enable the two ComboBox inside. so I tried to use "Shadows" and "Overrides" to redefine it :

```
Public WriteOnly Shadows Property Enabled() As Boolean
    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        cbo1.Enabled = Value 
        cbo2.Enabled = Value 
    End Set
End Property
```

But the problem is that I get two "Enabled" properties when I instanciate the new object.

[image]

Any help please !

Comment: Don't inherit UserControl, Instead inherit either ComboBox or simply Control.

Comment: `Enabled` property is not declared as virtual you can't override it. If you shadow it, yes there will be two properties each per declared type. I.e `CodLibCombo.Enabled` and `Control.Enabled` are different

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, so you think that even if I try to inherit from ComboBox or Control, I'll get the same result ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why you need to add one more Enabled property?

Comment: Sorry for the clearance of the question, I just added more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create your own Enabled property as this is handled in the base class. If the control has the Enabled property set to False then all controls in your user control will be set to False as well. No code is needed for this.

Note that by default the Enabled property of a control has no visible effect at design-time only at run-time, so you need to run your program so see the change.